# Asyncio event loop is closed when using asyncio.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm getting started to AsyncIO and AioHTTP, and i'm writing some basic code to get familiar with the syntax. I tried the following code that should perform 3 requests concurrently:

```
import time
import logging
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import json
from aiohttp import ClientSession, ClientResponseError
from aiocfscrape import CloudflareScraper

async def nested(url):
    async with CloudflareScraper() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()

async def main():
    URL = "https://www.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
    await asyncio.gather(nested(URL), nested(URL), nested(URL))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Here is the output:

```
raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

I don't understand why do i get that error, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What operating system are you running the code on?

Comment: I'm running this on Windows 10, Python 3.8

Comment: It looks like you're running into [this issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324). But it's very likely that your code is actually working, despite the unsightly message - you're just returning the contents from main() without printing it, so you have no output _other_ than the message.

Comment: Thank you a lot! So it's actually aiohttp raising the error. I'm relieved because i had no idea what could be behind this error

Comment: No, it's from ```asyncio.ProactorEventLoop``` related internal ```asyncio``` components that deals with IO event loop for Windows. I've encountered same issue with async TCP socket server.

Comment: Right! Thank you for clarifying, i'm going to suppress the error

Comment: Sadly you can't. I couldn't figure out how to suppress  single ```RuntimeError``` with ```try-except``` no matter where catch block is.

Comment: @jupiterbjy "No, it's from asyncio.ProactorEventLoop related internal asyncio components that deals with IO event loop for Windows" - Interestingly, [this comment](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324#issuecomment-552850307) make it seem like the issue is in aiohttp or at least fixable there.

Comment: Comment clearly says: "The fix of asyncio is very welcome, I'm happy to review the proactor's patch if any." - It's issue of ```ProactorEventLoop``` itself, not sure if there is any workaround for that though.

Comment: This is a know issue with Window, have a look at https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914. You can fix this issue by setting the event loop policy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Update

Originally I was recommending Greg's answer below:

```py
import asyncio
import sys

if sys.platform:
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Turned out, using `WindowsSelectorEventLoop` has *functionality issues* such as:

- Can't support more than 512 sockets
- Can't use pipe
- Can't use subprocesses

due to the fact that Windows uses [I/O completion Ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) unlike *nix - Therefore `SelectorEventLoop` is not designed for Windows nor is implemented as full.

If those limitations matters to you - You might be better off using lengthy workaround in this answer.

Check out more about differences at [documents](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-platforms.html#windows).

Or alternatively, consider using [Trio](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) over asyncio, which is much more stable and consistent.

```py
import trio


async def task():
    await trio.sleep(5)


trio.run(task)
```

---

#### Original post

I've finally figured out how to keep `ProactorEventLoop` running, preventing unsuccessful IO closure.

Really not sure why windows' Event loop is so faulty, as this also happens for `asyncio.open_connection` and `asyncio.start_server`.

To workaround this, you need to run event loop in forever loop and close manually.

Following code will cover both windows and other environments.

```
import asyncio
from aiocfscrape import CloudflareScraper


async def nested(url):
    async with CloudflareScraper() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()


async def main():
    await nested("https://www.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo")


try:
    assert isinstance(loop := asyncio.new_event_loop(), asyncio.ProactorEventLoop)
    # No ProactorEventLoop is in asyncio on other OS, will raise AttributeError in that case.

except (AssertionError, AttributeError):
    asyncio.run(main())
    
else:
    async def proactor_wrap(loop_: asyncio.ProactorEventLoop, fut: asyncio.coroutines):
        await fut
        loop_.stop()

    loop.create_task(proactor_wrap(loop, main()))
    loop.run_forever()
```

This code will check if new `EventLoop` is `ProactorEventLoop`.
If so, keep loop forever until `proactor_wrap` awaits `main` and schedules loop stop.

Else - possibly all other OS than Windows - doesn't need these additional steps, simply call `asyncio.run()` instead.

IDE like Pycharm will complain about passing `AbstractEventLoop` to `ProactorEventLoop` parameter, safe to ignore.

Comment: I tried this and i didn't get the error indeed. I hope this answer gets enough attention, since there are a lot of questions on the same problem, from what i've seen. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. How ironic that I couldn't figured this out with my repo for months - time to implement this workaround to see if this solution also applies to socket server.

Comment: It's an interesting solution and I do like it. However instead of manually closing the event loop, why not just set the policy?

Comment: Didn't even know there was option for it - After reading document it says "since python 3.8 ```ProactorEventLoop``` is default for windows." Not sure why this faulty loop using IOCP is default, but I'm also concerned about going against dev's decision.

Comment: Surprised to see it works fluently, thanks for tip!

Comment: I ran into the "event loop closed" error in a library that uses subprocess, so switching to the selector loop wasn't an option. I was still able to fix it with a one line change: replacing `asyncio.run(main())` with `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())`
Windows 10 / python 3.10.4.

Comment: @drsimonz that isn't an always viable solution sadly! if there's no single active event loop before execution of `main()` task, it will throw `DeprecationWarning` as there's no current event loop! As stated on [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html?highlight=get_event_loop#asyncio.get_event_loop) this will eventually throw an error instead.

Answer (score 8):

Whilst this has been answered and accepted. You can fix this issue with one line of code: `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())`

`Event loop is closed` is a known issue on Windows (see https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914). I suspect this will be fixed in later versions of Python. To get around the error, simply set the event loop policy to WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy.

If you plan to run the code on non-windows environment; then you'll want to either add an if statement to prevent error. E.g: `if sys.platform == 'win32'`. Or add code to set the policies.

**Working example:**

```
import asyncio
from aiocfscrape import CloudflareScraper
import sys

async def nested(url):
    async with CloudflareScraper() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            print(resp.status)
            return await resp.text()

async def main():
    URL = "https://www.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
    await asyncio.gather(nested(URL), nested(URL), nested(URL))

# Only preform check if your code will run on non-windows environments.
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    # Set the policy to prevent "Event loop is closed" error on Windows - https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: **BEWARE!** Even though this answer might hide away the exception, it degrades functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67964463/

Comment: @T.Todua Nice catch, didn't saw this one - I'll add it at top of my answer so people hopefully see the limitations. Not being able to use subprocess on `WindowsSelectorEventLoop` is kinda big deal for some,