# What are SelectorEventLoop and ProactorEventLoop in python asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp, event-loop

What exactly are `SelectorEventLoop` and `ProactorEventLoop`? How are they different?

I was testing the use of *asyncio* and *aiohttp* in python on Windows, then got an error `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`.
Looked up and found a workaround, but I did not understand the root of the error.
Many people seem to touch on the concept of `SelectorEventLoop` and `ProactorEventLoop` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860576/asyncio-event-loop-is-closed-when-using-asyncio-run) and also [here](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2608).

I read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloops.html) but couldn't grasp the concept.
Could anyone explain these concept in easier terms?

Comment: In short: Windows uses [I/O Completion Ports](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports) for processing multiple async IO operations (not to go in-depth, Windows implements things differently at a "deeper" level (for lack of better words), and to access different IO asynchronously you *must* use this interface). Therefore, two implementations were made: `SelectorEventLoop`, which is the default for most platforms (MacOS, Linux, etc.), and `ProactorEventLoop`, which is the Windows-specific event-loop that is capable of making IO bound calls on Windows machines.

Comment: Note that `SelectorEventLoop` still works on Windows, but only works with sockets, and not pipes. Since pipes are a process communication tool it requires more in-depth kernel-level implementations, and on Windows, it is named "I/O Completion Ports", which is what `ProactorEventLoop` uses.

Comment: More details about differences: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-platforms.html#windows